# How to shadow to view to all 4 sides in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get shadow at all 4 sides, but currently getting only at 3 side.

```
alertCard.layer.cornerRadius = 10
alertCard.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
alertCard.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5 //0.5
alertCard.layer.shadowRadius = 1 //3
alertCard.layer.shadowColor  = yellowColor?.cgColor
```

[image]

Please suggest way to get shadow all 4 sides

Comment: this is just one view..with border at 3 side except top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `UIView` Extension, I managed to achieve this in one of my apps:

```
extension UIView {

    open func generateOuterShadow() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = layer.cornerRadius
        view.layer.shadowRadius = layer.shadowRadius
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = layer.shadowOpacity
        view.layer.shadowColor = layer.shadowColor
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        view.clipsToBounds = false
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        superview?.insertSubview(view, belowSubview: self)

        let constraints = [
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        ]
        superview?.addConstraints(constraints)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    shadowView.generateOuterShadow() // Add

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change offSet to zero

```
alertCard.layer.shadowOffset =  .zero
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set shadow offset to `.zero` :

```
alertCard.layer.cornerRadius = 10
alertCard.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
alertCard.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
alertCard.layer.shadowRadius = 3
alertCard.layer.shadowColor  = yellowColor?.cgColor
```